# django: getattr function (get field name)

Tags: django, getattr

I can't make the function getattr work. Here is my code:

```
print ConfigConsModel()._meta.get_all_field_names() #['codesectrepmodel', 'configCons', 'id']
modelInstance=ConfigConsModel()
newAttrName1=getattr(modelInstance, "configCons")
print newAttrName1 #empty -> PB
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `#empty -> PB` What does this mean? PB == Problem? What problem? empty string, it doesn't print what you expect ... ?

Comment: Yes PB means problem, newAttrName1 should contain the name of the attribute "configCons", not an empty string.

Comment: no, `newAttrName1` contains value of `modelInstance.configCons`, which is obviously empty, because you've just initialized `modelInstance` as   empty `ConfigConsModel`

Comment: `newAttrName1` would contain the value (not the name) of the field whose name you provide as a 2nd argument

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the usage of this function... Solved!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
modelInstance=ConfigConsModel()
```

This initializes `modelInstance` as new (empty) instance of `ConfigConsModel` class

```
newAttrName1=getattr(modelInstance, "configCons")
```

This line is equivalent to

```
newAttrName1=modelInstance.configCons
```

It does not get attribute's name, it gets it's value. Which of course is empty.

Comment: what if i want to get modelinstance.customer.name?

Comment: @Jack: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: i mean, you are getting model fields right? if a model have the fields like ID, Name, Phone, this technique will work right, but what if my model have a forghin key, like Customer?
i might want to get Customer name?
i will do that in normal case (model.customer.name)
but if i give it like value = getattr(modelinstance, "customer.name")
or 
value = getattr(modelinstance, "customer__name") it would probably not work, how to this scenario?

Comment: @Jack: You'd have to do `getattr(getattr(modelinstance, "customer"), "name")`